# Cadena de datos muy larga con LONG - ORACLE

Tags: sql, html5, oracle-11g

Estoy tratando de guardar este código en la base de datos Oracle:

```
    <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="contenedor_item">
        <div class="titulo_hijo">
            <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
            <div class="iconos">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarAcordeon" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarAcordeon" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <div class="nieto">
                <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                <div class="iconos">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nieto">
                <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                <div class="iconos">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nieto">
                <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                <div class="iconos">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn-categoria" value="Agregar una categoria">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor_item">
        <div class="titulo_hijo">
            <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
            <div class="iconos">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarAcordeon" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarAcordeon" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <div class="nieto">
                <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                <div class="iconos">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nieto">
                <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                <div class="iconos">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nieto">
                <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                <div class="iconos">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn-categoria" value="Agregar una categoria">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor_item">
        <div class="titulo_hijo">
            <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
            <div class="iconos">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarAcordeon" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarAcordeon" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <div class="nieto">
                <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                <div class="iconos">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nieto">
                <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                <div class="iconos">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nieto">
                <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                <div class="iconos">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn-categoria" value="Agregar una categoria">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pero me sale un mensaje diciendo que la cadena es larga, ¿Habrá otra forma de insertar el código que tengo a Oracle? Mi meta es que un Administrador pueda modificar la página a su gusto, y cuando guarde los cambios, los otros usuarios puedan visualizar dichos cambios.

**En Oracle esto fue lo unico que cree**

```
CREATE TABLE TBLPRUEBA
(
   ID_ACORDEON NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
   DESCRIP_ACORDEON LONG
);
```

**INSERT**

```
    CREATE TABLE TBLPRUEBA
(
ID_ACORDEON NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
DESCRIP_ACORDEON CLOB 
);

INSERT INTO TBLPRUEBA VALUES(1, to_clob('<div class="contenedor">
        <div class="contenedor_item">
            <div class="titulo_hijo">
                <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                <div class="iconos">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarAcordeon" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarAcordeon" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hijo">
                <div class="nieto">
                    <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                    <div class="iconos">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nieto">
                    <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                    <div class="iconos">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nieto">
                    <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                    <div class="iconos">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn-categoria" value="Agregar una categoria">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contenedor_item">
            <div class="titulo_hijo">
                <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                <div class="iconos">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarAcordeon" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarAcordeon" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hijo">
                <div class="nieto">
                    <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                    <div class="iconos">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nieto">
                    <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                    <div class="iconos">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nieto">
                    <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                    <div class="iconos">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn-categoria" value="Agregar una categoria">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contenedor_item">
            <div class="titulo_hijo">
                <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                <div class="iconos">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarAcordeon" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarAcordeon" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hijo">
                <div class="nieto">
                    <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                    <div class="iconos">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nieto">
                    <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                    <div class="iconos">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nieto">
                    <p class="parrafo">Titulo editable</p>
                    <div class="iconos">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editarCategoria" alt="Editar" title="Editar">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminarCategoria" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn-categoria" value="Agregar una categoria">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta declarando una variable de tipo `CLOB` y ha esa variable le pasas tu cadena de html.

Te dejo el ejemplo:

```
DECLARE 
    str_html CLOB := '
<div class="contenedor">
    ...
</div>
';  
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO TBLPRUEBA VALUES(1, str_html);
    COMMIT;
END; 
/
```

> Nota: no e probado el query, solo es un ejemplo o guia para que lo
>   adaptes y lo pruebes. El mismo lo e sacado del siguiente post [How to
>   write oracle insert script with one field as CLOB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3890901). El cual en
>   resumida dice: Tenga en cuenta que las cadenas de SQL no pueden tener
>   más de 4000 bytes, mientras que PL/SQL puede tener cadenas de hasta
>   32767 bytes. El cual hace una inserción de una cadena
>   grande a través de un bloque anónimo.

Comment: FUNCIONO A LA PERFECCIÓN!!!! MUCHAS GRACIAS :)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo cambiado **LONG** POR **CLOB** Ya que desde hace muchas versiones atras oracle recomienda el des uso de **LONG** y recomienda usar **CLOB**.
tambien es mucho mayor asi que te ayudara con tu problema.

1. LONG  máximo 2 Gigabytes
2. CLOB  máximo 4 Gigabytes

Debes hacer el insert asi:

```
INSERT INTO TBLPRUEBA VALUES(1,to_clob( 'html string' ));
```

opcion 2:

```
DECLARE
  str CLOB;
BEGIN
  str := 'html string';
  INSERT INTO TBLPRUEBA VALUES(1,str);
END;
/
```

Comment: Aún me sigue apareciendo el mensaje "La cadena es muy larga" :(

Comment: Habrá otro tipo de dato mayor a CLOB?

Comment: Utiliza un BLOB, solo que debes de convertir toda tu cadena de html a un array de byte, tengo un proyecto el cual guardo unas plantillas de xslt en un BLOB y hasta ahora no me ha dado problema.

Comment: Acabo de cambiar a BLOB y sigue el mensaje de que la cadena es muy larga.

Comment: CREATE TABLE TBLPRUEBA
(
ID_ACORDEON NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
DESCRIP_ACORDEON BLOB
);

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa el tama;o para `BLOB` es de 4GB tambien es equivalente a `CLOB`, pero `CLOB` es el extended de `LONG` miestra `BLOB` el de `RAW` saludos!

Comment: Entonce el problema no es el CLOB y el BLOB, por que no creo que el fragmento de codigo html que quiere guardar pese mas  de 4GB.

Comment: pregunta como haces el insert??

Comment: Espero no este pasando esa cadena html por query string.

Comment: YA ESTA, ACTUALICE LA PREGUNTA

Comment: ya te agrege como debes hacer el insert :v

Comment: wow, eso no sabia, ahora lo pruebo :)

Comment: Perdón que te siga molestando @Bryro, pero aún no me sigue saliendo. Aumente el html tambien al inicio y nada.

Comment: Y tambien cambie el tipo de dato de mi columna a "CLOB"

Comment: entonces deben ser los caracteres especiales los que te te estan molestando debes sanearlos!

Comment: YA LOS SANEE, PERO INCREÍBLEMENTE AUN NO PUEDO INSERTAR LAS ETIQUETAS

Comment: Aun me sigue apareciendo el mensaje de que esta muy largo

Comment: entonces debes sanear la cadena alguna caracter debe estar afectandote el insert!